# Seemingly incomplete vectorization of text in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, search, tsvector

Can anyone please explain what seems to be an incomplete vectorisation of the text in this Postgres SQL query?

```
with x as 
(
select 'the organic organization organizes organisms'::text as t,
to_tsvector('english','the organic organization organizes organisms'::text) tvect
)
SELECT t, 
left(ts_headline(t, 'organic'::tsquery), 100),
ts_rank_cd(tvect, 'organic'::tsquery)
 FROM x
WHERE (tvect @@ 'organic'::tsquery) 
order by ts_rank_cd(tvect, 'organic'::tsquery) desc;
```

when i try to search by actual text in this case 'organic', the search result is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to_tsvector stems 'organic' to 'organ' (in english anyway).  And to_tsquery does so as well, but you aren't using that.  By using ::tsquery you are casting directly, which bypasses the stemmer.

And 'organic' doesn't match 'organ'.  You have to apply the same stemming rules to both sides of the match operator.

Comment: Thank you. modified my code to be:
`with x as 
(
select 'the organic organization organizes organisms'::text as t,
'the organic organization organizes organisms'::tsvector tvect
)
SELECT t, 
ts_headline(t, 'organic'::tsquery),
ts_rank_cd(tvect, 'organic'::tsquery)
 FROM x
WHERE (tvect @@ 'organic'::tsquery) 
order by ts_rank_cd(tvect, 'organic'::tsquery) desc;`
Just curious, why is the ts_rank a value of 0?

Comment: ts_rank need position information, but ::tsvector doesn't produce any.  If you want evade stemming, use the 'simple' config rather than 'english'.